# Is it "Forty centuries was a long time" or "Forty centuries were a long time"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I need to know if the verb form should be singular or plural in such sentences.

Comment: You're probably thinking of the period as a monolithic whole, so use singular agreement: *was*.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. "Forty centuries" here refers to a period of time, which is singular.

Answer (score 0):

"Forty centuries was a long time" is correct. though it's a plural noun, it makes sense of a singular meaning. for example, forty kilometers is a long distance to walk.

Comment: Why, but why, though, is the point.

Answer (score -1):

There's two subtle different meanings of "time" at play here.

If you were to say *"Forty centuries is a long time"* then it's a simple statement of fact, which applies at any point in time, past, present or future.

With *"Forty centuries **was** a long time"* it sounds like you are talking about something that happened to you (or someone else), ie a **specific** time period.  That's because the use of "was" implies it's no longer a universal thing, like with "is", and that you must be talking about something more concrete and specific.

It's unlikely that you mean the second sense, since nobody ever experienced a forty-century time period.

Comment: "There's two" ?

Comment: The question is not about the tense but number agreement.

Comment: @Kris I went for the colloquial rather than the more formally correct "there are". :)

Comment: @Kris I think tense and number are related here, due to the modifying effect of "was" on the meaning of the sentence, which goes beyond the plural/singular question.

Comment: We are on Q&A for "English Language & Usage" and the OP has just joined in.